# How do I get the opposite (negation) of a Boolean in Python?

Tags: python, boolean

For the following sample:

```
def fuctionName(int, bool):
    if int in range(...):
        if bool == True:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Is there any way to skip the second if-statement? Just to tell the computer to return the opposite of the boolean `bool`?

Comment: This is probably just pseudocode, but `int` and `bool` are both builtin names (for the types they represent), and should not be used as variable names.

Comment: yes, it's just a pseudo-code ,, demonstration purposes only...

Comment: `if x == True:` should be written `if x:`.

Answer (score 332, accepted):

To negate a boolean, you can use the [`not` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

```
not bool
```

Or in your case, the `if`/`return` blocks can be replaced by:

```
return not bool
```

Be sure to note the [operator precedence rules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence), and the negated `is` and `in` operators: [`a is not b`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not) and [`a not in b`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

Comment: Also, `int in range (....)` is inefficient. It will create a list and then perform a linear search. Better than `x in range(low, high)` is `low <= x < high`.

Comment: Note that `not None` will return False. At least for me that's not what I'd expect. I'd expect `not None` to be `None` so `not` can be used to negate even if the return value might be `None`. The way it's implemented in Python you'll have to verify you actually got a boolean first.

Comment: I think I need to mention the `int in range(...)` mentioned by @MRAB is inefficient only before Python 3 since unless you run `range(...)` through `list(...)` it's using a massively (<- my understanding) efficient way. I haven't checked the C code for that, though, so I dunno how they did that.

Comment: The C code is here, it's basically a custom `__contains__` for the range object: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a330365ca5ae836075f306334ab648bf23471481/Objects/rangeobject.c#L430-L431

Answer (score 110):

### The [`not` operator](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html?highlight=operator#not) (logical negation)

Probably the best way is using the operator `not`:

```
>>> value = True
>>> not value
False

>>> value = False
>>> not value
True
```

So instead of your code:

```
if bool == True:
    return False
else:
    return True
```

You could use:

```
return not bool
```

### The logical negation as function

There are also two functions in the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#module-operator) module [`operator.not_`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.not_) and it's alias [`operator.__not__`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.__not__) in case you need it as function instead of as operator:

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.not_(False)
True
>>> operator.not_(True)
False
```

These can be useful if you want to use a function that requires a predicate-function or a callback.

For example [`map`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) or [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> lst = [True, False, True, False]
>>> list(map(operator.not_, lst))
[False, True, False, True]

>>> lst = [True, False, True, False]
>>> list(filter(operator.not_, lst))
[False, False]
```

Of course the same could also be achieved with an equivalent `lambda` function:

```
>>> my_not_function = lambda item: not item

>>> list(map(my_not_function, lst))
[False, True, False, True]
```

### Do not use the bitwise invert operator `~` on booleans

One might be tempted to use the bitwise invert operator `~` or the equivalent operator function [`operator.inv`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.inv) (or one of the other 3 aliases there). But because `bool` is a subclass of `int` the result could be unexpected because it doesn't return the "inverse boolean", it returns the "inverse integer":

```
>>> ~True
-2
>>> ~False
-1
```

That's because `True` is equivalent to `1` and `False` to `0` and bitwise inversion operates on the bitwise representation of the **integers** `1` and `0`.

So these cannot be used to "negate" a `bool`.

### Negation with NumPy arrays (and subclasses)

If you're dealing with NumPy arrays (or subclasses like `pandas.Series` or `pandas.DataFrame`) containing booleans you can actually use the bitwise inverse operator (`~`) to negate **all** booleans in an array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([True, False, True, False])
>>> ~arr
array([False,  True, False,  True])
```

Or the equivalent NumPy function:

```
>>> np.bitwise_not(arr)
array([False,  True, False,  True])
```

You cannot use the `not` operator or the `operator.not` function on NumPy arrays because these require that these return a single `bool` (not an array of booleans), however NumPy also contains a logical not function that works element-wise:

```
>>> np.logical_not(arr)
array([False,  True, False,  True])
```

That can also be applied to non-boolean arrays:

```
>>> arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0])
>>> np.logical_not(arr)
array([ True, False, False,  True])
```

### Customizing your own classes

`not` works by calling `bool` on the value and negate the result. In the simplest case the [truth value](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) will just call `__bool__` on the object.

So by implementing [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) (or [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) in Python 2) you can customize the truth value and thus the result of `not`:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __bool__(self):
        print('__bool__ called on {!r}'.format(self))
        return bool(self._value)

    __nonzero__ = __bool__  # Python 2 compatibility

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{self.__class__.__name__}({self._value!r})'.format(self=self)
```

I added a `print` statement so you can verify that it really calls the method:

```
>>> a = Test(10)
>>> not a
__bool__ called on Test(10)
False
```

Likewise you could implement the [`__invert__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__invert__) method to implement the behavior when `~` is applied:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __invert__(self):
        print('__invert__ called on {!r}'.format(self))
        return not self._value

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{self.__class__.__name__}({self._value!r})'.format(self=self)
```

Again with a `print` call to see that it is actually called:

```
>>> a = Test(True)
>>> ~a
__invert__ called on Test(True)
False

>>> a = Test(False)
>>> ~a
__invert__ called on Test(False)
True
```

However implementing `__invert__` like that could be confusing because it's behavior is different from "normal" Python behavior. If you ever do that clearly document it and make sure that it has a pretty good (and common) use-case.

Answer (score 12):

Python has a "not" operator, right? Is it not just "not"? As in,

```
  return not bool
```

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer here is the most correct for the given scenario.

It made me wonder though about simply inverting a boolean value in general. It turns out the accepted solution here works as one liner, and there's another one-liner that works as well. Assuming you have a variable "n" that you know is a boolean, the easiest ways to invert it are:

```
n = n is False
```

which was my original solution, and then the accepted answer from this question:

```
n = not n
```

The latter IS more clear, but I wondered about performance and hucked it through `timeit` - and it turns out at `n = not n` is also the FASTER way to invert the boolean value.

Comment: Don't use `n is False` for truth testing.

Answer (score 3):

You can just compare the boolean array. For example

```
X = [True, False, True]
```

then

```
Y = X == False
```

would give you

```
Y = [False, True, False]
```

Comment: For a Numpy array, maybe, but for a standard Python list, this is incorrect. Since the OP does not mention either, I fail to see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most compact version is

> self.foobar ^= True

Which does not require repeating the whole name and works with pure booleans.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to implement a **toggle**, so that anytime you re-run a persistent code its being negated, you can achieve that as following:

```
try:
    toggle = not toggle
except NameError:
    toggle = True
```

Running this code will first set the `toggle` to `True` and anytime this snippet ist called, toggle will be negated.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same outcome, which I found useful for a pandas dataframe.

As suggested below by mousetail:

```
bool(1 - False)

bool(1 - True)
```

Comment: Is there no logical inversion of pandas dataframes, like with numpy arrays?